# how to get attribute value of a different cell on button click in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

in a **datatable**, in the same row, I have a button and an img
what I want is to get the **src** attribute of the image when I click on the button.
i can get the whole  data. but can't figure out how to get the src alone.

```
$('#exemptionsTable tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
        var data = exemptionsTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

        var img = data[11]; // result = <img width="100" height="50" class="PhotoId" src="/ExemptionImages/bf3f2111-f7c5-4208-896f-5e71b96bb66d.png">
 });
```

how can I get the src attribute value from the img object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that what you are intending to do is to parse a *HTML* string, one option is to use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Sample snippet to help you with:

```js
var stringToParse = '<img width="100" height="50" class="PhotoId" src="/ExemptionImages/bf3f2111-f7c5-4208-896f-5e71b96bb66d.png">';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var data = parser.parseFromString(stringToParse, "text/html");
var element = data.getElementsByClassName("PhotoId");
console.log(element[0].src);
```

---

Not sure you need to use `data` function in there.

Looking at the code, there seems it can be achieved more easily as you are holding the `DOM` object:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = $("#exemptionsTable > img");
  console.log(data.prop("src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exemptionsTable">
  <img width="100" height="50" class="PhotoId" src="/ExemptionImages/bf3f2111-f7c5-4208-896f-5e71b96bb66d.png">
</div>
```

Comment: the DOMParser did the trick. thank you. 
I cannot use your second suggestion because it will not get the value of the attribute for the desired `row`